# Colocar un link en una cardview android conectado con la base de datos en Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 public void setLink(String link)
{TextView post_link = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.linkText);
 post_link.setText(link);}
```

estoy creando una lista recycleview y dentro de ellas unas cardview conectadas a mi base de datos firebase. pero **como hago para colocar un (link) en cada cardview que me diriga a ciertas web**, puede ser un boton de "Go". esta url para ir a "go" deberia estar conectada a firebase, para que se actualize segun las necesidades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varios métodos, si tienes un link en tu `TextView`, puedes simplemente habilitar los links mediante el método [setLinksClickable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinksClickable(boolean)) :

```
myTextView.setLinksClickable(true);
```

por ejemplo:

```
public void setLink(String link)
{ 
  TextView post_link = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.linkText);
   post_link.setLinksClickable(true);
   post_link.setText(link);

}
```

de esta forma todos los "links" serán sensibles!

Esta forma también puede configurarse directamente en el `TextView`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://stackoverflow.com"

        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

---

La otra forma es mediante un Intent al dar click a la vista:

```
post_link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Gracias, se me ocurrio una idea algo osada. colocar el link en trasparente e hice que el textview abarcara todo el contenedor de la imagen, con la opcion android:autolink:"web".

Comment: Es una forma similar a la de setLinksClickable() pero aquí defines las propiedades directamente en la vista (TextView), revisa la respuesta.

Comment: Alguna idea para hacer el mismo proceso, de llamar el String Url desde Firebase y asignarle esa url a un FloatingActionButoom?

Comment: Es similar a la segunda forma que comparto , usa un OnClickListener, por ejemplo  myFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   //llamar url!
  )};