# Como colocar url de mi web a un FAB

Tags: android

Agrego mi código:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    FloatingActionButton miFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myFAB);

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);

        miFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Abre webview
                browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
}
```

Necesito asignar una Url, al FAB, para que abra al webview, ese boton FAB se encuentra dentro de una Recycle View.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.notification);

  //Verifica que tu id activity_main_webview este declarado en tu layout notification
  WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

  FloatingActionButton miFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.miFab); 
  miFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v) { 
       //Abre webview
       browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
     } 
  });
}
```

o también puedes intentar añadiendo dentro del onClick

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tu_Url"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Nota: Recuerda añadir a tu URL **http://** o  **https://**

Comment: Keops en este caso que seria el "miView"?

Comment: De la vista padre que contenga tu FAB por ejemplo si fue dentro de Fragment pero si la llamada la estas haciendo desde un Activity no es necesario

Comment: @ElihatCaceres lo elimine para que no te cause confusión

Comment: Ok  ya no me salen errores, pero al lanzar la aplicacion se cierra. lo he colocado dentro de " @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notification);"

Comment: Que error te muestra? Si lo agregas es de ayuda. Has checado que los componentes de vista que utilizas están en tu layout?

Comment: Ese FAB esta dentro de una Recycle View, Tiene eso algo que ver?

Comment: Posiblemente aunque, para ser mas acertados, busca el error que te esta mostrando en el LogCat

Comment: Tengo lo siguiente:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at beraka.rubio.Notification.onCreate(Notification.java:55)

Comment: Verifica que el nombre de tu FAB en tu layout sea el mismo que tienes en tu método onCreate

Comment: he añadido el codigo en la parte superior si lo quieres revisar. el error ahora esta en el WebView

Comment: Agrega tu layout notification, activity_main_webview esta dentro de tu layout notification?

Comment: @ElihatCaceres actualice mi respuesta

Comment: Me di cuenta que no se pueden usar FAB dentro de recycleview. He aplicado las sugerencias y funcionan perfecto, pero no dentro de una recycle view

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo que te comenté en la pregunta:

[Colocar un link en una cardview android conectado con la base de datos en Firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42193/colocar-un-link-en-una-cardview-android-conectado-con-la-base-de-datos-en-fireba)

**simplemente agrega un `OnClickListener` al botón**:

```
myFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```